# Sql query bringing out other results

Tags: mysql

When i run this query i get products.total greater than 10000.

```
SELECT p.id
     , p.title
     , a.country
     , p.total 
  FROM products p
  JOIN product_tags pt 
    ON p.id = pt.product_id 
  JOIN address a 
    ON p.address_id = a.id 
  JOIN product_styles ps 
    ON p.id = ps.product_id 
 WHERE p.allow = 'Yes' 
   AND ps.styles in ('Abstract Expressionism')
   AND p.total between 500 and 10000 
   AND p.title LIKE '%abstract%' 
    OR pt.tags LIKE '%abstract%' 
    OR a.country LIKE '%abstract%' 
    OR p.subject LIKE '%abstract%' 
 GROUP 
    BY p.id
```

Comment: Please, provide proper detail sample table and format the code properly.

Answer (score 1):

Check Below updated version Or condition was creating issue.

```
   select DISTINCT products.id, 
      products.title,
      address.country, 
      products.total
 from products 
 inner join product_tags on products.id = product_tags.product_id 
 inner join address on products.address_id = address.id 
 inner join product_styles on products.id = product_styles.product_id 
 where products.allow = 'Yes' and product_styles.styles in ('Abstract Expressionism') 
 and products.total between 500 and 10000 
 and (products.title like '%abstract%' or product_tags.tags like '%abstract%' or address.country like '%abstract%' or products.subject like '%abstract%' )
```

Comment: Your answer worked .Thank you very much.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for the update I didn't realize that just review the problem and provided the solution. I will take care next time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.id
              , p.title
              , a.country
              , p.total 
  FROM products p
  JOIN product_tags pt 
    ON p.id = pt.product_id 
  JOIN address a 
    ON p.address_id = a.id 
  JOIN product_styles ps 
    ON p.id = ps.product_id 
 WHERE p.allow = 'Yes' 
   AND ps.styles IN ('Abstract Expressionism')
   AND p.total BETWEEN 500 AND 10000 
   AND 
     ( p.title LIKE '%abstract%' 
    OR pt.tags LIKE '%abstract%' 
    OR a.country LIKE '%abstract%' 
    OR p.subject LIKE '%abstract%'
     );
```